# What is SourceArn in aws lambda permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

This is my cft for lambda, I upload the jar file to s3 and then upload to lambda through s3, I completed the LambdaRole and LambdaFunction section, in the permission section, what should be the SourceArn? I went through the lambda official doc but didn't find any example.

Also, can anyone take a look to see if this cft is correct or not? Thanks!

```
ConfigurationLambdaRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'configuration-sqs-lambda'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
                - events.amazonaws.com
                - s3.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSQSFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess

  ConfigurationLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: 'configuration service with lambda'
      FunctionName: 'configuration-lambda'
      Handler: com.lambda.handler.EventHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: Java 11
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 120
      Code:
        S3Bucket: configurationlambda
        S3Key: lambda-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      Role: !GetAtt ConfiguratioLambdaRole.Arn

  ConfigurationLambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - ConfigurationLambdaFunction
          - Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: ''
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#permissions-resource-serviceinvoke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a Role to run your lambda, a lambda function, and permissions for something to invoke that lambda.  The `SourceArn` is the thing that will invoke the lambda.  So in your case it sounds like you want an S3 bucket to invoke the lambda, so the SourceArn would be the ARN of the S3 bucket.

[This tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) relates to what you are doing--specifically step 8 under the "Create the Lambda function" section.

Your CF template generally looks correct.  The only thing I see that will be assuming this role is lambda.amazonaws.com, so the role may *not* need to list the following in the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` section:

```
        - events.amazonaws.com
        - s3.amazonaws.com
```

Also see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html